# How to get user pool name from its id

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

When I log in to the user pool using username and password from my web application, I get id token. By parsing it, I can extract the Cognito group, username, user pool id, etc. by using python library. But Now I want to get the user pool name from these attributes. How can I get it?

I need to find it from id token or from extracted info of id token.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Cognito User Pool ID received with the JWT token, you can invoke [describeUserPool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#describeUserPool-property) method in AWS Cognito SDK to receive the details of the User Pool. It will return the name of the User Pool along with some other attributes.